# Spring MVC + Security testing with CSRF

Tags: java, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security, csrf-protection

I know that the question already exists on topic, but still not working for me. I'm using Spring 4 MVC / Security stack with CSRF protection enabled. I follow the spring blog http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html, but still getting the 403 forbidden code.

Here is the setup of my test;

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
}
```

The method to test is a post method dealing with a formBean, here is how i perform the test method request;

```
this.mockMvc.perform(
    post("/uploadFile")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED) 
    .with(user("user").authorities(authorities))
    .with(csrf())
    .flashAttr("filesUploadForm",filesUploadForm)               
)
.andExpect(status().isOk())
.andExpect(view().name(FileController.VIEW_SHOW_FILES));
```

i set a user with the RequestPostProcessor, with specific authorities;

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("PERM_UPLOAD_FILE"));
```

Because my method controller is as follow;

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('PERM_UPLOAD_FILE')")
@RequestMapping(value = ROUTE_UPLOAD_FILE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadFile(Model model, 
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("filesUploadForm") FilesUploadForm       filesUploadForm,
        BindingResult result, 
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
...
```

This is working like a charm when all security is up **EXCEPT CSRF** (csrf disable=true). When i enable CSRF protection, even if i'm using the .SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.csrf(), i'm still getting a *java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<403>*.
I also try to explicitly inject the token as param, nothing changed.

I'm quite lost, Thanks a lot for your help guyz!

Phackt.